# cannot get material-ui Toolbar to use variant='dense'.... always stays 64px height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tried this hello world AppBar/Toolbar to use the variant='dense' format.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const app =
  <AppBar>
    <Toolbar variant='dense'>
      <Typography color='inherit'>MyApp</Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>;
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

This media queries never fires.

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (orientation: landscape)
.MuiToolbar-root-36 { min-height: 48px; }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The media query works perfectly, the CSS which doesn't work is `MuiToolbar-root-36` this is due to the dynamic `className` generation from the `Toolbar` component.

In case u want to add custom CSS for the `Toolbar` or `Appbar` use CSS API's in `@material-ui/core` module.